# Displaying GIF on Android

Tags: java, android, xml, layout, gif

So, all I am trying to do is to display a GIF fullscreen in the background, and have a second layer displaying google ads come over the GIF when a user taps the screen.
On an AVD it works fine, however on my phone it shows only some frames, and I doesn't show at all on other peoples phones. The textViews show up, but the background remains black.

Here is my MainActivity:

```
package pt.quintas.migratoris;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.*;

import pt.quintas.migratoris.util.SystemUiHider;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * An example full-screen activity that shows and hides the system UI (i.e.
 * status bar and navigation/system bar) with user interaction.
 *
 * @see SystemUiHider
 */
public class MigratorisActivity extends Activity {

    private Thread migrationCounterT;
    private long migrationCounter = 0;

    /**
     * Whether or not the system UI should be auto-hidden after
     * {@link #AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS} milliseconds.
     */
    private static final boolean AUTO_HIDE = true;

    /**
     * If {@link #AUTO_HIDE} is set, the number of milliseconds to wait after
     * user interaction before hiding the system UI.
     */
    private static final int AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS = 3000;

    /**
     * If set, will toggle the system UI visibility upon interaction. Otherwise,
     * will show the system UI visibility upon interaction.
     */
    private static final boolean TOGGLE_ON_CLICK = true;

    /**
     * The flags to pass to {@link SystemUiHider#getInstance}.
     */
    private static final int HIDER_FLAGS = SystemUiHider.FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION;

    /**
     * The instance of the {@link SystemUiHider} for this activity.
     */
    private SystemUiHider mSystemUiHider;
    private AdView adView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.migratoris_activity);

        final View controlsView = findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls);
        final View contentView = findViewById(R.id.GIFSingle);

        // Create the adView.
        adView = new AdView(this);
        adView.setAdUnitId("a--------------");
        adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

        // Lookup your LinearLayout assuming it's been given
        // the attribute android:id="@+id/mainLayout".
        LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.fullscreen_content_controls2);

        // Add the adView to it.
        layout.addView(adView);

        // Initiate a generic request.
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();

        // Load the adView with the ad request.
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        // Set up an instance of SystemUiHider to control the system UI for
        // this activity.
        mSystemUiHider = SystemUiHider.getInstance(this, contentView, HIDER_FLAGS);
        mSystemUiHider.setup();
        mSystemUiHider.setOnVisibilityChangeListener(new SystemUiHider.OnVisibilityChangeListener() {
                    // Cached values.
                    int mControlsHeight;
                    int mShortAnimTime;

                    @Override
                    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
                    public void onVisibilityChange(boolean visible) {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2) {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator API is available
                            // (Honeycomb MR2 and later), use it to animate the
                            // in-layout UI controls at the bottom of the
                            // screen.
                            if (mControlsHeight == 0) {
                                mControlsHeight = controlsView.getHeight();
                            }
                            if (mShortAnimTime == 0) {
                                mShortAnimTime = getResources().getInteger(
                                        android.R.integer.config_shortAnimTime);
                            }
                            controlsView.animate()
                                    .translationY(visible ? 0 : mControlsHeight)
                                    .setDuration(mShortAnimTime);
                        } else {
                            // If the ViewPropertyAnimator APIs aren't
                            // available, simply show or hide the in-layout UI
                            // controls.
                            controlsView.setVisibility(visible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
                        }

                        if (visible && AUTO_HIDE) {
                            // Schedule a hide().
                            delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
                        }
                    }
                });

        // Set up the user interaction to manually show or hide the system UI.
        contentView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (TOGGLE_ON_CLICK) {
                    mSystemUiHider.toggle();
                } else {
                    mSystemUiHider.show();
                }
            }
        });

        // Upon interacting with UI controls, delay any scheduled hide()
        // operations to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
        // while interacting with the UI.


        //start thread
        migrationCounterT = new Thread() {

              @Override
              public void run() {
                try {
                  while (!isInterrupted()) {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      @Override
                      public void run() {
                          migrationCounter += 1;
                        TextView migrationTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textCounter);
                        migrationTV.setText(migrationCounter + " light years.");
                      }
                    });
                  }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
              }
            };

            migrationCounterT.start();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Trigger the initial hide() shortly after the activity has been
        // created, to briefly hint to the user that UI controls
        // are available.
        delayedHide(100);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
      adView.pause();
      super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
      super.onResume();
      adView.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
      adView.destroy();
      super.onDestroy();
    }


    /**
     * Touch listener to use for in-layout UI controls to delay hiding the
     * system UI. This is to prevent the jarring behavior of controls going away
     * while interacting with activity UI.
     */
    View.OnTouchListener mDelayHideTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if (AUTO_HIDE) {
                delayedHide(AUTO_HIDE_DELAY_MILLIS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    };

    Handler mHideHandler = new Handler();
    Runnable mHideRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mSystemUiHider.hide();
        }
    };

    /**
     * Schedules a call to hide() in [delay] milliseconds, canceling any
     * previously scheduled calls.
     */
    private void delayedHide(int delayMillis) {
        mHideHandler.removeCallbacks(mHideRunnable);
        mHideHandler.postDelayed(mHideRunnable, delayMillis);
    }
}
```

This is my layout xml:

```
<FrameLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/MainLayout"
    tools:context=".MigratorisActivity" >

    <!--
         The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc.
    -->

    <pt.quintas.migratoris.GIFView
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp" 
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/GIFSingle">
    </pt.quintas.migratoris.GIFView>

     <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14pt"
        android:padding="25dip"

        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:text="You have migrated for:" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textCounter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dip"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="14pt"
        android:padding="16dip"

        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:text="" />

    <!--
         This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows.
    -->

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls"
            style="?buttonBarStyle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/black_overlay"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            tools:ignore="UselessParent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/fullscreen_content_controls2"
                style="?buttonBarStyle"
                android:paddingTop="21dp"
                android:layout_width="480dp"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/black_overlay"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </FrameLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Because Android does not support GIF naturally I used a GIFView class that simply uses the Movie Class to display the GIF. This is my GIFView Class:

```
package pt.quintas.migratoris;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Movie;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;


public class GIFView extends View {
    private Movie movie;
    private long moviestart;
    private int gifCounter;

    public GIFView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) throws IOException {
        super(context, attrs);
        movie = Movie.decodeStream(getResources().getAssets().open("migratorisgif01.gif"));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

        float heightScale = canvas.getHeight() / 960.0f;
        float widthScale = canvas.getWidth() / 720.0f;
        canvas.scale(widthScale, heightScale);

        super.onDraw(canvas);

        long now = android.os.SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
        Paint p = new Paint();
        p.setAntiAlias(true);
        if (moviestart == 0)
            moviestart = now;
        int relTime;
        relTime = (int) ((now - moviestart) % movie.duration());
        float test = movie.duration();
        // movie.setTime(relTime);
        if (gifCounter == movie.duration()) {
            gifCounter = 0;
        } else
            gifCounter += 100;
        movie.setTime(gifCounter);

        movie.draw(canvas, 0, 0);
        this.invalidate();
    }
}
```

When debugging on my phone I get this LogCat: 
(So this is where the GIF shows up, but stuttering)

```
01-29 15:58:43.582: I/ApplicationPackageManager(4487): cscCountry is not German : VOD
01-29 15:58:44.113: I/Ads(4487): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("B246DEAA33A5FAE6AF9FF0A2F44B5CBC") to get test ads on this device.
01-29 15:58:44.113: I/Ads(4487): Starting ad request.
01-29 15:58:44.233: I/webclipboard(4487): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@405e5e50
01-29 15:58:44.333: V/webview(4487): OnSizeChanged: Enter 
01-29 15:58:44.343: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4487): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
01-29 15:58:44.653: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4487): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
01-29 15:58:44.673: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:44.744: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4487): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
01-29 15:58:44.894: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:45.164: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:45.484: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:45.704: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:45.905: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:46.115: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:46.345: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:46.505: V/webview(4487): ZoomScale 3 mPreserveZoom: false
01-29 15:58:46.625: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:46.786: I/Ads(4487): Ad finished loading.
01-29 15:58:46.836: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:47.046: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:47.256: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:47.466: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:47.666: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:47.867: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:48.077: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:48.287: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:48.487: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:48.717: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:48.928: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:49.268: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:49.578: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:49.859: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:50.149: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:50.429: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:50.719: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:50.940: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:51.170: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:51.370: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:51.600: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:51.830: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:52.111: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:52.391: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:52.681: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:52.921: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:53.132: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:53.332: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:53.532: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:53.732: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:53.932: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:54.183: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:54.513: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:54.793: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:55.084: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:55.374: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:55.594: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:55.804: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:56.004: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:56.225: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:56.565: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:56.845: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:57.146: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:57.436: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:57.676: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:57.876: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:58.087: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:58.327: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:58.607: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:58.897: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:59.188: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:59.488: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:58:59.778: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:00.129: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:00.359: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:00.559: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:00.779: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:00.989: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:01.220: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:01.430: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:01.640: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:01.840: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:02.050: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:02.251: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:02.451: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:02.651: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:02.851: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:03.051: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:03.252: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:03.452: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:03.652: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:03.862: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:04.072: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:04.283: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:04.483: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:04.683: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:04.883: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:05.093: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:05.294: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:05.504: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:05.714: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:05.914: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
01-29 15:59:05.934: W/KeyCharacterMap(4487): Can't open keycharmap file
01-29 15:59:05.934: W/KeyCharacterMap(4487): Error loading keycharmap file '/system/usr/keychars/melfas_touchkey.kcm.bin'. hw.keyboards.65537.devname='melfas_touchkey'
01-29 15:59:05.934: W/KeyCharacterMap(4487): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
01-29 15:59:06.184: E/(4487): Wink AGIF Error 7 700 100 7
```

Running it on the AVD Nexus: 
(This is when it works fine)

```
01-29 12:06:35.800: D/dalvikvm(877): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads206081988.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
01-29 12:06:35.990: D/dalvikvm(877): DexOpt: --- END 'ads206081988.jar' (success) ---
01-29 12:06:35.990: D/dalvikvm(877): DEX prep '/data/data/pt.quintas.migratoris/cache/ads206081988.jar': unzip in 1ms, rewrite 191ms
01-29 12:06:36.050: D/dalvikvm(877): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 238K, 9% free 3147K/3452K, paused 30ms, total 34ms
01-29 12:06:36.090: I/Ads(877): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("B3EEABB8EE11C2BE770B684D95219ECB") to get test ads on this device.
01-29 12:06:36.110: I/Ads(877): Starting ad request.
01-29 12:06:36.140: V/WebViewChromium(877): Binding Chromium to the main looper Looper (main, tid 1) {b1dac978}
01-29 12:06:36.160: I/chromium(877): [INFO:library_loader_hooks.cc(112)] Chromium logging enabled: level = 0, default verbosity = 0
01-29 12:06:36.160: I/BrowserProcessMain(877): Initializing chromium process, renderers=0
01-29 12:06:36.320: E/chromium(877): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
01-29 12:06:36.340: E/chromium(877): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
01-29 12:06:36.340: E/chromium(877): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(153)] No suitable EGL configs found.
01-29 12:06:36.340: E/chromium(877): [ERROR:gl_surface_egl.cc(620)] GLSurfaceEGL::InitializeOneOff failed.
01-29 12:06:36.340: E/chromium(877): [ERROR:gpu_info_collector.cc(86)] gfx::GLSurface::InitializeOneOff() failed
01-29 12:06:36.360: W/chromium(877): [WARNING:proxy_service.cc(888)] PAC support disabled because there is no system implementation
01-29 12:06:36.470: D/dalvikvm(877): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 76K, 8% free 3285K/3552K, paused 38ms, total 40ms
01-29 12:06:36.480: I/dalvikvm-heap(877): Grow heap (frag case) to 4.346MB for 1127536-byte allocation
01-29 12:06:36.550: D/dalvikvm(877): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 6% free 4386K/4656K, paused 64ms, total 64ms
01-29 12:06:36.970: D/gralloc_goldfish(877): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
01-29 12:06:37.970: I/Choreographer(877): Skipped 85 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-29 12:06:41.950: I/Choreographer(877): Skipped 184 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-29 12:06:43.810: I/Choreographer(877): Skipped 182 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
01-29 12:06:45.300: I/Choreographer(877): Skipped 151 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

Running on other phones this is what I get:
(This is when the GIF simply doesn't appear)

```
01-29 15:34:06.195: E/SQLiteLog(28567): (14) cannot open file at line 30241 of [00bb9c9ce4]
01-29 15:34:06.195: E/SQLiteLog(28567): (14) os_unix.c:30241: (2) open(/FileSyetmQuota.db) - 
01-29 15:34:06.195: D/WebKit(28567): ERROR: 
01-29 15:34:06.195: D/WebKit(28567): SQLite database failed to load from /FileSyetmQuota.db
01-29 15:34:06.195: D/WebKit(28567): Cause - unable to open database file
01-29 15:34:06.195: D/WebKit(28567): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
01-29 15:34:06.195: E/SQLiteLog(28567): (14) cannot open file at line 30241 of [00bb9c9ce4]
01-29 15:34:06.195: E/SQLiteLog(28567): (14) os_unix.c:30241: (2) open(/NotificationPermissions.db) - 
01-29 15:34:06.195: D/WebKit(28567): ERROR: 
01-29 15:34:06.195: D/WebKit(28567): SQLite database failed to load from /NotificationPermissions.db
01-29 15:34:06.195: D/WebKit(28567): Cause - unable to open database file
01-29 15:34:06.195: D/WebKit(28567): external/webkit/Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(71) : bool WebCore::SQLiteDatabase::open(const WTF::String&, bool)
01-29 15:34:07.760: D/skia(30145): Wink AGIF Move Constructer End 17, totalTime : 1700
01-29 15:34:07.880: D/dalvikvm(30145): GC_CONCURRENT freed 194K, 6% free 12423K/13191K, paused 13ms+2ms, total 27ms
01-29 15:34:07.880: D/dalvikvm(30145): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 7ms
01-29 15:34:07.955: D/dalvikvm(30145): DexOpt: --- BEGIN 'ads970080158.jar' (bootstrap=0) ---
01-29 15:34:08.020: D/dalvikvm(30145): DexOpt: --- END 'ads970080158.jar' (success) ---
01-29 15:34:08.025: D/dalvikvm(30145): DEX prep '/data/data/pt.quintas.migratoris/cache/ads970080158.jar': unzip in 0ms, rewrite 66ms
01-29 15:34:08.065: D/dalvikvm(30145): GC_CONCURRENT freed 206K, 7% free 12623K/13447K, paused 11ms+12ms, total 35ms
01-29 15:34:08.070: I/Ads(30145): Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("F8E5DAD99BDAB8DA57F0BA3BBB1CFF6C") to get test ads on this device.
01-29 15:34:08.070: I/dalvikvm(30145): Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.getDefaultUserAgent, referenced from method abr.a
01-29 15:34:08.070: W/dalvikvm(30145): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3330: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.getDefaultUserAgent (Landroid/content/Context;)Ljava/lang/String;
01-29 15:34:08.070: D/dalvikvm(30145): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0011
01-29 15:34:08.080: I/Ads(30145): Starting ad request.
01-29 15:34:08.085: I/dalvikvm(30145): Could not find method android.webkit.WebSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture, referenced from method abz.<init>
01-29 15:34:08.085: W/dalvikvm(30145): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 3345: Landroid/webkit/WebSettings;.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture (Z)V
01-29 15:34:08.085: D/dalvikvm(30145): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x003d
01-29 15:34:08.145: I/webclipboard(30145): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@41f1de60
01-29 15:34:08.165: I/webclipboard(30145): clipservice: android.sec.clipboard.ClipboardExManager@41f1de60
01-29 15:34:08.180: V/webkit(30145): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {41ef7ab0}
01-29 15:34:08.200: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(30145): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
01-29 15:34:08.225: D/dalvikvm(30145): GC_CONCURRENT freed 370K, 8% free 12740K/13703K, paused 12ms+12ms, total 41ms
01-29 15:34:08.240: V/webkit(30145): BrowserFrame constructor: this=Handler (android.webkit.BrowserFrame) {41f61850}
01-29 15:34:08.275: D/libEGL(30145): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
01-29 15:34:08.290: D/libEGL(30145): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
01-29 15:34:08.295: D/libEGL(30145): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
01-29 15:34:08.300: D/(30145): Device driver API match
01-29 15:34:08.300: D/(30145): Device driver API version: 10
01-29 15:34:08.300: D/(30145): User space API version: 10 
01-29 15:34:08.300: D/(30145): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
01-29 15:34:08.355: D/OpenGLRenderer(30145): Enabling debug mode 0
01-29 15:34:08.400: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(30145): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
01-29 15:34:08.405: E/GooglePlayServicesUtil(30145): The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included.
01-29 15:34:11.315: I/GATE(30145): <GATE-M>DEV_ACTION_COMPLETED</GATE-M>
01-29 15:34:11.365: I/Ads(30145): Ad finished loading.
01-29 15:34:11.415: D/dalvikvm(30145): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 92K, 7% free 12784K/13703K, paused 22ms, total 22ms
```

Any suggestions? I am so confused as to why it has these 3 running results...

Thanks for your time, have a good one.

Comment: have you got any solution...

Comment: Not really, it is just not supported natively by android. Maybe now in recent versions it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

1.Insert the following dependency to build.gradle file of your app.

```
  implementation 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.23'
```

2.Insert the following to build.gradle file of your project.

```
  allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
  }
```

3.Usage code from XML.

```
  <pl.droidsonroids.gif.GifImageView 
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/w_gif" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" 
    android:tint="@color/white"/>
```